# how to expand items of tuple as argument os system call?

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, tuples

I want to expand tuple items i have collected from sys.argv to be passed as argument

like below

```
os.system('git send-email ' + *args)
```

but its giving error at `*args`

Comment: You should use ```subprocess.call()```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call(['git', 'send-email'] + list(args))
```

See [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module).

Comment: does the method call returns ?

Comment: @san, `subprocess.call` returns exit status of the program.

Answer (score 2):

would it be a simple as?

```
os.system('git send-email ' + ' '.join(args))
```

Comment: required reading when generating string as a command https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/OS_Command_Injection_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html and https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['git', 'send-email']
cmd.extend(args)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```